# Send GSM Module data to server and Retrieve from android phone

Tags: java, android, sockets

We have a electronic board on which there is sim card.

We want to

1. every 1 minute send some data (e.g. temperature, humidity...) to our server.
2. have server save data on database
3. retrieve these data on our android phone.

So far I wrote a simple java program as a server that opens a socket and read the data and saves them on mySQL.

I am wondering what is the best way to retrieve the data on android device? Should I use JSON?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can develop a REST web service that delivers the information to your android phone. I would recommend using OAuth 2 for your Web Service. [Cybens Technologies](http://www.cybens.ca) have a mobile/desktop solution that connects to a distant server, sends GPS data and deliver data to mobile phones. I think it is 20$/month.